# WaitForElement in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Currently, I am using Thread.sleep to make the scripts to wait for certain element to be loaded. Execution takes long time.. Instead this, i need something waitforElement once it is displayed i need to continue my execution rather this Thread.sleep..

Can someone tell me that the below logic looks ok??

```
package com.test.utility;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class WaitForElement extends globalVariables {

    public static void waitfor(String locator) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait Test_Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            WebElement locatorvalue = common.getObject(locator);
            Boolean click = Test_Wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeSelected(locatorvalue));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("The element is not found");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes it looks ok. Are there any problems?

Comment: i did not try this.. need to remove entire thread.sleep so want to confirm before apply this logic.. Thanks

Comment: Usually it is better to try and fail, try and fail, try and fail etc until you solve it :) This is how we learn and grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this similar code in my project and it works for me.